# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'MaterialRequest'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to access form data in a queryset and it throws the following error:

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'MaterialRequest'

**Views.py**

```
def form_valid (self, form):
    docket = form.save(commit=False)
    print("material request id is", form.cleaned_data['sales_order'])
    s_o = form.cleaned_data['sales_order']
    MaterialRequest.objects.filter(id=s_o).update(is_allocated = True)
    docket.save()
    messages.success(self.request, 'The Docket was created with success!')
    return redirect('employee:allotment-view')
```

in the print statement it says that s_o is 1, but I can't equate it with the id in query?
What is it that I am doing wrong and how can I change that?

Here's the traceback:

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  172.         return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  142.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "C:\Users\Rahul\yantra_packs\yantra_packs\packsapp\views.py" in form_valid
  227.         MaterialRequest.objects.filter(id=s_o).update(is_allocated = True)

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  836.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  854.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1253.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1277.                     split_subq=split_subq,

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
  1215.         condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_lookup
  1085.         lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in __init__
  18.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup
  68.             return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  947.         return int(value)

Exception Type: TypeError at /employee/allotment-form/
Exception Value: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'MaterialRequest'
```

Comment: Could you provide the corresponding Form class? It sounds like Django is already retrieving the right `MaterialRequest` object for you.

Comment: @frankie567 as you can see in the traceback it highlights that the error is in data retrieval

Comment: What I mean is that, depending on how you defined your form, Django **is** able to retrieve the full object from a given primary key. Said another way, `s_o` is not the id but the `MaterialRequest` you are looking for.

That's why it could help to see your form class.

Comment: I have updated the question with view and traceback

Comment: Good but, could also give the form class in your `forms.py` (the one where you define all the fields)?

Comment: `s_o is not the id but the MaterialRequest` This actually cleared my doubt.. I added `        s_o = form.cleaned_data['sales_order'].id` id in the end and it works perfectly. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily remove one of the steps in your code, cause you are receiving MaterialRequest object, so no need for looking for it again:

```
def form_valid (self, form):
docket = form.save(commit=False)
print("material request id is", form.cleaned_data['sales_order'])
s_o = form.cleaned_data['sales_order']
s_o.update(is_allocated = True)
docket.save()
messages.success(self.request, 'The Docket was created with success!')
return redirect('employee:allotment-view')
```

Should work without using unneeded query.
Also, we should assume that id is primary key, so you should probably use get instead of filter, because filter will aready give you queryset instead of single object.